# Synology NAS cannot connect to Git server repository

Tags: git, tortoisegit, synology

I've installed Synology [Git Server](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/help/Git/git?version=6) on my NAS.  Then, I installed Git on my Windows 10 laptop.  I've followed several posts to create a bare repository on the NAS.  I've already committed the local repo.  I now would like to push the updates to the NAS.  However,  I can't seem to connect to the NAS.  I get the following error in the resulting dialog:

> git.exe push --progress "synologygit" main fatal: unable to connect to
> DiskStation214: DiskStation214[0:
> xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]: errno=Unknown error
> DiskStation214[1: 192.168.0.47]: errno=Unknown error
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (4266 ms @ 8/10/2021 5:20:11
> PM)

I'm in the process of switching from SVN to Git.  I'm using the following URL to access the repo on the NAS:

> git://DiskStation214/*reponame*

I've checked within the DiskStation and I can't find anything obvious there.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The linked doc talks about SSH and `ssh://` protocol, not `git://`

Comment: the `git:` protocol in your git url says that there should be a git server listening directly on a port.  This is very rarely the case as it is unprotected.  You may be following the wrong tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the comment by 'phd' was helpful, it did not fully solve my problem.  I did need to change to using `ssh://` protocol, but, that did not resolve my problem.  I continued to get an error when trying to access the repo.

After logging into DSM and checking `Control panel/Terminal`, I stumbled on the port setting.  It was incorrectly set to `33` (for some reason).  I set it to `22` and I was then allowed access to the repo.